# limit number of children with storage rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to limit user to upload at most 4 images.
storage rules can limit a number of children in specific node?
this is my storage rules without children limitation.

```
    service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users/{uid}/{filename} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example - e.g., data, and the code that you have tried

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092953/limit-number-of-files-in-a-firebase-storage-path

Comment: thanks for the fast replay, the only way is with firebase functions? there is no way with rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, there isn't a way to achieve this using storage security according to the [documentation for storage security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/).

The related question Frank linked in the comments has a good answer. Another way you could make this happen is a Realtime Database trigger with Cloud Functions for Firebase. If you already write the download URLs to the database, use Cloud Functions for Firebase to count the number of children and limit them, as shown in [this example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/limit-children).