# Set Firebase Storeage file size and File number limit

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am successfully uploading **images** using AngularFire2 to Firebase Storage.

I have the following upload code.

```
this.AfStorage.ref(`images/${userId}/${timeStamp}`).putString(base64Image,'data_url');
```

There are a few issues that I want to solve.

1. How can I set a limit on the file size? Meaning I want the user to be able to upload files which are less than 10mb.
2. How can I limit the file number? Meaning I want one user to be able to upload only 3 files.

If there are no firebase server size solutions do suggest some client size solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To limit the size of uploads, see this [example from the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#full_example):

> ```
> service firebase.storage {
>  match /b/{bucket}/o {
>    match /images {
>      // Cascade read to any image type at any path
>      match /{allImages=**} {
>        allow read;
>      }
>
>      // Allow write files to the path "images/*", subject to the constraints:
>      // 1) File is less than 5MB
>      // 2) Content type is an image
>      // 3) Uploaded content type matches existing content type
>      // 4) File name (stored in imageId wildcard variable) is less than 32 characters
>      match /{imageId} {
>        allow write: if request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024
>                     && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')
>                     && request.resource.contentType == resource.contentType
>                     && imageId.size() < 32
>      }
>    }
>  }
> }
> ```

There is no way to limit the number of files with security rules, so you'll have to look at workarounds such as shown here:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ZtJPcEJr0Mc (seems to hint this is possible, but I've never tried it)
- [limit number of children with storage rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339006/limit-number-of-children-with-storage-rules/45339123#45339123)
- [Limit number of files in a firebase storage path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092953/limit-number-of-files-in-a-firebase-storage-path)